# Saving time in DB in UTC and converting back to client time?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

In the backend I use the NestJs, TypeORM and PostgreSQL database. How to correctly save the time to the database in UTC and when requested, return the time to the client in the desired time zone of the client?
At the moment I save the time in the same format that comes from the client, for example

```
2022-07-18 01:00:00
```

I understand that this is wrong. What is the best practice for this?

Comment: your data type should be `timestampz` instead of `timestamp`. please refer [this](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-timestamp) tutorial.